# Oracle - Altering behavior of trigger depending if it is triggered by job

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need my trigger (which sends messages on update of table) to behave certain way if it is triggered by job. This job runs every hour and is sending abundant messages.
Is there any way I can do it.

I tried following to determine if invoker is a job, but did not seem to work:

```
select count(1) into nIsJob from V$SESSION x where x.sid in (select t.session_id from all_scheduler_running_jobs t) and x.sid=sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');
```

whole trigger is this:

```
create or replace trigger tg_spot_in_other_hour
  before update
  on BREAKS 
  for each row
declare
 vBody     VARCHAR2(4000);
 nIsJob NUMBER;
begin
  
  select count(1) into nIsJob from V$SESSION x where x.sid in (select t.session_id from all_scheduler_running_jobs t) and x.sid=sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');
 
if (:new.id_break_types NOT IN (2) or (:new.id_break_types = 5 and nIsJob=0)) and TRUNC(:new.BREAK_TIME / gv.fis / 60 / 60)<>TRUNC(:old.BREAK_TIME / gv.fis / 60 / 60) and (:new.break_date >= sysdate or :old.break_date >= sysdate) then

select 'Break on '||ch.label||' ' into vBody
from channels ch
where ch.id_channels=:new.id_channels;

vBody:=vBody||:new.break_date||' moved from '||pcg_system.num2dur(:old.break_time,'HH:MM')||' to '||pcg_system.num2dur(:new.break_time,'HH:MM');


for x_b in (select  c.id_backoffice,c.contract_number,c.label
from spots s, contracts c
where c.id_contracts=s.id_contracts
and s.id_breaks=:new.id_breaks) loop

INSERT INTO messages
      (id_users,
       header,
       message,
       created)
values (x_b.id_backoffice,'Spot moved to different hour',vBody||' Contract: '||x_b.contract_number||' ('||x_b.label||')',sysdate)  ;

end loop;

end if;

end tg_spot_in_other_hour;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use context to change the behaviour of the trigger, via [`DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.html#GUID-6F1765B9-B716-4A44-AFB7-7C2608E080A4).

You can change the trigger to have a `WHEN` clause that looks for a context value, e.g. `client_info`:

```
create or replace trigger tg_spot_in_other_hour
  before update
  on BREAKS 
  for each row
  when (sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') is null
    or sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') != 'FROM_JOB')

declare
...
```

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B__GUID-62B802FB-993F-45FF-A4D3-1B002131A248):

> **WHEN (condition)**
> Specifies a SQL condition that the database evaluates for each row that the triggering statement affects. If the value of condition is TRUE for an affected row, then *trigger_body* runs for that row; otherwise, *trigger_body* does not run for that row. The triggering statement runs regardless of the value of condition.

Then in the procedure your job runs, set the context at the start:

```
dbms_application_info.set_client_info('FROM_JOB');
```

You can/should also clear it again at the end, in case the session is left alive and reused (so maybe in an exception handler too):

```
dbms_application_info.set_client_info(null);
```

So now when the triggering event is caused by your job the `WHEN` clause will evaluate to false and the trigger body won't be executed; otherwise it will evaluate to true and it will still send messages.

There's nothing stopping someone else manually setting the context but if you think that's possible you can make sure the value used is unusual or unlikely to be picked randomly; and/or use a combination of context values (info, module, action...).

---

Using `SCHEDULER_JOB`, `FG_JOB_ID` or `BG_JOB_ID` as @PaulW suggests is gong to be simpler, as you don't need to change the job's procedure to set something yourself. I'll leave this here because this can be useful in other situations, like distinguishing between calls from an application, or single vs batch (but not scheduler!) jobs, or during an upgrade...

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous ways to do this. Here are a couple others:

1. Look at the `pname` of the current session to see if it's a job process:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     INTO var_exists
     FROM v$session s,
          v$process p
    WHERE s.sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
      AND s.paddr = p.addr
      AND p.pname LIKE 'J%'

   IF var_exists > 0
   THEN
      -- is a job
   END IF;
   ```
2. Or even more simply, use a `SYS_CONTEXT` value like `SCHEDULER_JOB`, `FG_JOB_ID` or `BG_JOB_ID`:

   ```
   IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SCHEDULER_JOB') = 'Y'
   THEN
     -- is a job
   END IF;
   ```

or

```
   IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID') IS NOT NULL
   THEN
     -- is a job
   END IF;
```

You can also match up the `dba_scheduler_jobs.job_name` with the `v$session.action` field. Lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
owa_util.who_called_me(owner, name, lineno, caller);
```

It will return all the details that you can differentiate if it is fired by the Job or not.

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/OWA_UTIL.html#GUID-5DE6750D-1EBC-40A7-AF22-849765DD3EF6) for details.

Comment: This seems to be good, but when I call it during job(raised app error with returning values from WHO_CALLED_ME) it does not return anything(NULL), is that normal ?

Comment: no, it should at least give some results

Comment: If I remember correctly, unlike with functions, procedures and packages, this doesn't work with triggers. Maybe because triggers are seen as part of the SQL enginge rather than part of the PL/SQL environment.